# Работа методов в Python: почему некоторые методы изменяют объект, а другие нет?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос немного нубский, но почему некоторые методы изменяют объект, а другие нет?

К примеру - есть массив array, назовем его m.

`m.sort()` - изменит объект m

`m.ravel()` - не изменит, а только возвратит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, как работают методы классов зависит от представления использования объекта, которое формируется в голове программиста.

Например, `m.sort()` может изменить внутреннее состояние объекта `m`, а может вернуть новый измененных объект. Поэтому, есть документация, в которой описываются методы.

---

Приведу примеры реализации функции сортировки:

- **c++**: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/
- **java**: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)
- **c#**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx
- **qt**: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#sort

По ним видно, что разработчики считают, что функция `sort` должна изменять внутреннее состояние, а не возвращать новое.

А вот если бы она называлась `sorted`, тогда она была бы обязана возвращать отсортированную копию.

Например, в `python` [есть такая функция](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

Comment: sort() vs. sorted() это [Command-query separation](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CQRS)